# Azure SDK: How do I get the public IP address of the current machine my software is running on at runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to figure out how to capture the following IP address at run-time using the Azure SDK:

[image: Azure SDK image]

How do I get this information via the Azure SDK *from within the software that is actually running on this VM.* The AWS SDK has a trivially easy static method for looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Get Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460804.aspx) operation will give you what you need?

This really should be easier in Azure though...